# Error while searching similar date in timestamp postgress

Tags: postgresql, jqgrid

I am searching a date from jqGrid in timestamp variable in postgres database.
From grid I am sending search option 'op' - 'like' and searchtype as 'string'.

I got following stacktrace.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function lower(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
 Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
 Position: 359
 at     org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
... 72 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

`lower(text)` makes text low case. you cant put timestamp as as. try instead `lower(timestamptz_column::text)` or use `to_char` for specific format

Comment: thanks for reply, but I am searching date value in timestamp variable. So I am searching using LIKE option, How do I modify my query ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM InfoHeader i INNER JOIN Location l WHERE i.cCode = 1 AND  i.dCode = 1 AND i.posteddate like  '2016-06-27'

Comment: `Exception: ERROR: function lower(timestamp without time zone) does not exist` is your error. and there is no lower(timestamtz) in the query => this is not the query